# SSRS graph relative interval

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

In SSRS chart i have values like MIN value 0.10 and max value is 30000, because of these values the graph shows like:

[image: Output coming like this]

but i want the graph like :

[image: Actual output of graph like]

there is **relative** option in other reporting tool to show graph like above.

How to specify relative interval in SSRS graph,

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use logarithmic scale in vertical axis properties.

I check that box and put value 10.

find below image:

[image]